# jQuery fails on DOM element inserted by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote a simple jQuery function on class named `close`.

```
$(function () {
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().fadeTo(400, 0, function () { // Links with the class "close" will close parent
            $(this).slideUp(400);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Its working well but if I insert new DOM element using AJAX this function fails? Why it is so? Though I know solution that to write same function on page that is inserted through AJAX response. I did it and it's working. Why is it not working globally?

I tried to replace the `$(".close").click(function () {` with `$(".close").on("click", function(event){` but it didn't gave me exact solution of my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is becuase for click event to work the element should be present in the document...use  `on` delegated event

```
$(document).on("click",".close",function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeTo(400, 0, function () { // Links with the class "close" will close parent
        $(this).slideUp(400);
    });
    return false;
});
```

adding you click event after ajax success function works but then I prefer to go with the `on` delegated event (since `on` in jquery was introduce for this purpose)..

I recommend you to use the closest static parent,  than the `document` itself for better performance...

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about delgated on event

Answer (score 4):

Because jQuery binded `click` event to elements when DOM was ready. It doesn't watch for new elements matching selectors so any elements added after will **not** have click event binded to your function. To do this, you must do `$('.close').click(...)` after AJAX request is finished.

Comment: actually, if you're going to statically rebind _every_ `.close` element over and over then you must first _unbind_ all existing handlers, or you'll end up with duplicate handlers being registered.

Comment: Indeed, `$('.close').unbind('click')` should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/):

```
$("body").on('click', '.close', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    return false;
});
```

- Also, you do not need to slideUp after fading out, as the element is **already hidden**.
- Secondly, the default fade duration is already 400, you do not need to state the speed again.

Comment: Yes, exactly it is. Everything is same. It only work if I use same js code on inserted element.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using 'live' method.

```
$(".close").live('click',function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeTo(400, 0, function () { // Links with the class "close" will close parent
        $(this).slideUp(400);
    });
    return false;
});
```